# Pause animation between each rotation for five seconds

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working on this demo. How can I add five seconds delay to this animation between each rotate?

```css
.card {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: rotate 4s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 4s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    50% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the overall animation time to 9 seconds (= 4 seconds for animation  + 5 seconds for pause) and adjust the percentage steps accordingly, calculating the percentage of 4 seconds in relation to 9 seconds (= app. 44%)

```css
.card {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: rotate 9s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    22% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    44% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
```

Addition: Second version, where the pause is *between* the forward and backward rotation:

```css
.card {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: rotate 9s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    22% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    78% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
```

Another addition: Third version, with pauses between all rotations:

(just adjust the percentage values and animation time as desired)

```css
.card {
    background: #00f;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: rotate 20s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    25% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
```

Comment: Hi Johannes and thanks for this but yo are adding the delay between each rotate not between steps

Comment: @MonaCoder I added a second version, where the pause is in the middle and the second rotation phase is at the end (22% before 100% = 78%)

Comment: @MonaCoder And another one, with pauses between all rotation phases - probably that's what you meant

Answer (score 1):

You could do as suggested, and add a longer delay, or you could transition the keyframes between percentages to show a more notable gap between iterations if desired.

[More here](https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/)

```css
.card {
  background: #00f;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: rotate 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  20%,100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
   0%,25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  25%,50% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50%,80% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  80%,100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel this very close to what I want but why the content  inside the box is jumping

Comment: @MonaCoder you can make it smoother by adding/adjusting keyframe animation properties.. this is just a quick example. I'm having a look at another q at the mo, I'll look at it again in a few mins

Comment: @MonaCoder it's not really that it's "jumping" - it's that the 5 second delay between transitions here is obvious here because the start position is returned to after 5 seconds (and you're not turning it a full 360 degrees .. it would look smoother if you turned it 90 180 270 360 if you get my drift.. y'know? ) That's explanation but it can be adjusted to appear smoother

Comment: @MonaCoder I updated my answer - slightly less jumpy? You could add a delay at the start also (before rotate 5s infinite.. e.g. 5s rotate 5s infinite)