# How to rotate an image with CSS or JavaScript with pause in between every rotation?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a picture that I want to rotate from 0 to 90 stop 2s then continue from 90 to 180 then stop 2s to the 360 degrees any ideas thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839198/pause-animation-between-each-rotation-for-five-seconds

Comment: hi, perhaps [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) might be of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` and `setInterval` appropriately:

```js
const rotate = (image, degrees) => {
  image.style.transform = `rotate(${+degrees}deg)`;
}

const img = document.getElementById('js-logo');

const oneLoop = () => {
  setTimeout(() => rotate(img, 90), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => rotate(img, 180), 4000);
  setTimeout(() => rotate(img, 360), 6000);
}

oneLoop();
setInterval(() => oneLoop(), 6000);
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/JavaScript-logo.png/240px-JavaScript-logo.png" alt="JS Logo" width="120" height="120" id="js-logo">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with CSS animations:

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background:  linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);;
  animation: rotate-stop 10s infinite linear;
  transform: rotate();
}

@keyframes rotate-stop{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  5%, 25%{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  30%, 50%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  55%, 75%{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  80%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my answer. Nice answer. +1

Comment: woops sorry, i missed yours before posting this one! . Indeed I find concise/minimal examples easier to read through!

Answer (score 0):

An example for javascript.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var box = document.querySelector('.box');
  setInterval(function() {
          box.classList.toggle('rotate');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.rotate {
    animation: rotate 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure css example using animation keyframes.

If you calculate the time for each rotation animation, and each pause time, you can use css animate keyframe percentages to perform a sequence of desired css.

Here is an example below, see comments in css...

```css
/* any kind of html elem, img, div etc */
DIV {
  background: magenta;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: center;
  
  /* 4 rotations */
  /* 4 2sec pauses */
  /* 8 keyframes total */
  /* 2sec rotation time example */
  /* 8*2sec is 16s for complete sequence */
  animation: rotate-pause 16s infinite;
  
}

/* rotate and pause key frames */
@keyframes rotate-pause {
  /* 0 seconds */
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  /* 2 seconds */
  12.5% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  /* 4 seconds */
  25% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  /* 6 seconds */
  37.5% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  /* 8 seconds */
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  /* 10 seconds */
  62.5% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(270deg);
  }
  /* 12 seconds */
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(270deg);
  }
  /* 14 seconds */
  87.5% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
  /* 16 seconds */
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
  /* reloop if animate set to infinite */
}

/* demo reset css */
HTML {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

BODY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>Any kind of html elem: img, div...</div>
```